# Angular 6 - Deploy Angular 6 to Github Pages error

Tags: angular, github, angular-cli, angular-cli-ghpages

I want to deploy my angular project in github.

I get this error:

[image]

I try to build in dist directly but nothing. 
any help will be approciated

****Edit:

I try run git remote set-url.. and ngh --no-silent

currently I get this:

[image]

I guess it's related to dist folder according this line:

```
'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Yaffa\\todo-list\\dist\\index.html'
```

but I ran `ngh --dir=dist/todo-list`
and in `angular.json` file have:             `"outputPath": "dist/todo-list",`

so I could't understant what wrong

Comment: Can you run without silent option to get a detailed error (like it said in the error message)?

Comment: do you want to upload the code to github respository ?

Comment: @JoHTVS I update the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a lot of search..

what I did was:

1. I updated git version ( it is help to "`fatal: HttpRequestException encountered`" error).
2. I changed in `angular.json` the line to: `"outputPath": "dist/"` and copy all the files to dist folder directly.
3. in cmd ran:

   ```
   ngh setup 
   ngh --no-silent --dir=dist/
   ```

hope it is help

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

1) Firstly set origin by `git remote set-url ..`

2) Run with `ngh --no-silent` it will publish to git origin